# mongodb average, max and min every X documents

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I'm a newbie to mongo and I've seen it's power a bit, I need to make a map-reduce or aggregation that gives me the average, max and min of a value in a document like this:

```
{
_id: MongoId(""),
var: [integer with the variable id],
tim: timestamp in unix format,
val: [value can be int, float or string]
}
```

I'll deal with the strings by using an error display when the user is selecting a var that has strings as values, but for the other two I need to get the average, max and min every 10 or so documents the return must be like:

```
{
 var: [varid],
 avg: [average every 10],
 tim: [average tim],
 max: [max val in the 10 documents taken for this aggregation],
 min: [min val in the 10...]
}
```

The data example:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52cb898fds4bd6c24ae06a9e"),
"timestamp" : ISODate("2012-11-02T01:23:34.010Z")
"value" : 20
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52cb898bed4bd6c24ae34h56"),
"timestamp" : ISODate("2012-11-02T01:23:44.010Z")
"value" : 18
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52cb898bed4bd6c24ae06a9e"),
"timestamp" : ISODate("2012-11-02T01:23:54.010Z")
"value" : 25
}
...
```

The result for current 3 documents:

```
{
"timestamp" : ISODate("2012-11-02T01:23:44.010Z")
"avr" : 21,
"min" : 18,
"max" : 25
}
```

is there a way to do such thing or should I keep using the program to compute this instead of trying to get mongo to do it? the thing is that I'd like to do so because I have 10K documents per day for each var, and getting the averages for 10 days takes 100K documents, then counting the averages and all that takes a bit too much ram, I'm using php and it complains about it...(memory_limit must be below 512MB so...I have no option but to reduce the data transferred somehow...)

Any help will be appreciated and the best answer to fit my needs will be selected as such.

Comment: No source data provided or a sample desired output or any attempt at coding with a specific problem to overcome. These are all requirements of  a a clear question that is not off topic and is not too broad to answer. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you want the average, etc. of every tenth document or the average, etc. of each group of ten documents? Have you considered pre-aggregating the result by, say, computing a running sum, min, max in a separate document and then creating a new doc every 10 inserts? It would help clarify the question if you're indicate what you have considered or tried.

Comment: I want the average for each group of 10 documents